# how to restart web worker after stop

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am using web worker in my application. At certain point I want to stop my web worker and restart it. Stopping web worker is working fine, then I post some message to web worker, its not responding unless I reload the page. So I want to know how to restart the web worker after stop it without reloading the page.

Main.js

```
var ww = new Worker("worker.js");

function mainFunction(){
  //some code to form data
 f1(data,function(res){
      return res;
};

function f1(data,callback){
  ww.postMessage({'action':'action1'});
  ww.onmessage = function(event){
  var response = event.data;
  callback(response);
}

function f2(){
  ww.postMessage({'action':'stopWW'});
  ww.postMessage({'action':'reStartWW'});
  ww.onmessage = function(event){
    mainFunction();
  }
}
```

In worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message',function(e){
   var functionName=e.data.action;

   switch(functionName){
      case 'stopWW':
        self.close();
      break;
      case 'reStartWW':
        var test = {'key':1}
        self.postMessage(test);
      break;
      case 'action1':
         //do something
         self.postMessage(somedata);
         break;
      }
  });
```

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to initialize a new worker afterwards.

Comment: You mean again doing something like this.... var ww = new Worker("worker.js");

Comment: Yes, exactly, because there is no chance to revive the former terminated worker.

Comment: @Blauharley This seems like a pretty gaping deficiency if every time you want to stop a computation before it's done you have to create a whole new web worker to process the next item of data!

Answer (score 5):

Once `close()` or `terminate()` have been called, your worker is effectively closed and should be unreachable. You could create a new worker by calling `ww = new Worker("worker.js");` again, but the internal state of the first worker won't be acessible anymore.

Now if what you want is to essentially pause the worker, but keep it ready for restart with its internal state, I'd recommend simply switching listeners. Something like this :

```
function whenActive(event){
   var functionName=e.data.action;

   switch(functionName){
      case 'stopWW':
        self.removeEventListener("message", whenActive);
        self.addEventListener("message", whenNotActive);
        //do other stopping actions
        break;
      [...]//your other cases, but not "restartWW"
   }
}
function whenNotActive(event){
   var functionName=e.data.action;

   if(functionName === 'reStartWW'){
        self.addEventListener("message", whenActive);
        self.removeEventListener("message", whenNotActive);

       [...]//do other re-startup actions
   }
}

//start the cycle
self.addEventListener("message", whenActive);
```

Comment: I don't see how this is pausing the worker?  by pause i am imagining the web worker is running a long running computation for which it is impractical to try to insert periodic checks to see if it should stop, which you want to abort and then restart with new parameters.

Comment: @Michael that would be a totally different case. The worker in the question isn't performing a long-running op. I'm not aware that you can pause a long running operation other than periodically checking., or splitting the task into subtask, which highly depends on the task at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a webworker in a function, with this in you can call it multiple times.

```
var ww;
function setWebWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(ww) == "undefined") {
              ww = new Worker("worker.js");
       }
    }
}
setWebWorker();
```

[just like this page suggests.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webworker)

Answer (score 1):

How do you restart your worker?

Your declaration of the web worker is only done once at page load from looking at your code.

Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp for some color.

```
var w;

function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
    }
}

function stopWorker() { 
    w.terminate();
    w = undefined;
}
```